# Invoke workflow activity

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-2007, invoke

I've an issue when i try to invoke a workflow.

I've a global workflow and in this worflow, I'm using the "InvokeWorkflowActivity" activity to invoke a workflow. I bind the TagetWorkflow to my secondary workflow. I build and it's ok, i see my secondary workflow in my global workflow.

On SP, when I launch my global WF, it doesn't start in my secondary WF. I tried to debug it and in fact in goes to my secondary WF but doesn't stop at the breakpoint and stops the global WF and marks it as Complete.

After, I tried to launch my secondary WF alone, it works good !

So what's the matter ? What did I do wrong ?

Cheers

Skilpit

PS : I'm on MOSS 2007 with Infopath 2007

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround I found is to put all the WF in the same file. It's a big mess but it works fine.

Cheers